# Docker containers terminate on shell logout

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm running a debian backed docker container created with a `docker-compose up -d` detached command. It starts without problems and serves requests without issues, but it requires I keep logged-in with an active shell in order to keep containers running.

My docker-compose.yml file is as follows:

```
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:alpine
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'    
    volumes:
      - /data/docker/postgresql/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:Z
  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    volumes:
      - /data/docker/postgresql/pgadmin-data:/var/lib/pgadmin:Z
```

Everytime I restart the server it doesn't appears to start up until I log in.

The status of docker service, as per `systemctl status docker.service` is:

```
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2022-08-09 22:37:46 -03; 21min ago
TriggeredBy: ● docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com
   Main PID: 4359 (dockerd)
      Tasks: 11
        CPU: 1.396s
     CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
             └─4359 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
```

Even when all looks good, the moment I logout the shell session, the containers stop running.

Comment: you need a foreground process , like ENTRYPOINT ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]

Comment: I hope this helps you: [Postgresql & pgadmin4 powered by compose](https://github.com/khezen/compose-postgres)

Comment: @Mate both, postgres:alpine and pgadmin4:latest are images created to run as services, neither of them need additional foreground process

Comment: @Ali thanks for the repo. As far as I can see, the yaml file created there is doing essentially the same my yaml file is currently doing

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem I was having can be searched for:

**Rootless containers exit once the user session exits**

I finally could fix it after realizing i was using the rootless configuration for docker, and both containers where started using a normal user.

Linux stops processes started by a normal user if loginctl is configured to not use lingering, to prevent normal users to keep long-running processes executing in the system.

I've found this link that helped: [17) rootless containers exit once the user session exits](https://github.com/containers/podman/blob/main/troubleshooting.md#17-rootless-containers-exit-once-the-user-session-exits)

> You need to set lingering mode through loginctl to prevent user
> processes to be killed once the user session completed.

**Symptom**

Once the user logs out all the containers exit.

**Solution**

You'll need to either:

```
# loginctl enable-linger $UID
```

Comment: The best answer I found. Worked perfectly. Thank you very much!